# Interent Explorer Log is empty always

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

OS- Windows 7 Professional & Windows Server 2008 R2

In Event Viewer --> Application and Services logs --> Internet Explorer there is no log, it is always empty.

I need to check why my Internet Explorer crashes automatically, but I don't find any log. 
I have also try some registry setting to enable log. but unable to do the same. below is the print-screen.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I hope you'll pardon the very basic question, but did you make sure you have no active filters that would hide the logged events you are interested in? This is a rudimentary thing I have overlooked once too often.

Did you enable IE event logging as described in http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/Windows7/AdminTips/Miscellaneous/EnablingeventloggingforInternetExplorer.html ? If not, you'll want to add the registry entry and then restart the "Windows Event Log" service. and start a completely new IE session.

`Restart-Service eventlog
Get-Service eventlog`

You may also want to look at the Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250493(v=VS.85).aspx) to help you granularly enable and disable logging for different parts of IE.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for Dumb question. but just to inform you that there is no active filters, there is no such registry setting as described in link, still i have make that registry key and done the same, but no positive result.

Comment: I appologize, I didn't mean to suggest your question was dumb. I will rewrite mine to indicate that. I meant to suggest my question about filters was dumb, because it is basic-level thing that is easy to overlook.

Comment: @Param thank you for pointing out my dismissive tone. It was not deliberately and it was not directed at you. I've added a bit more detail and an additional resource. Hope this gets things working for you.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the previous answer: The location in the Registry may have changed with versions. This setting worked for me (Windows7 pro 64):

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\Feature_Enable_Compat_Logging]

"iexplore.exe"=dword:00000001
```

[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250493(v=VS.85).aspx) (near bottom)