# Internet Explorer event logs missing

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, windows-server-2008

I have an issue with Server 2008 and Windows 7 client machines -- the event viewer log for Internet Explorer 10 is empty.

I've googled this for the best part of my morning with no joy.

Currently tried:

- Checked IE logs are enabled in event viewer.
- Browsed to location of event logs and noticed the date modified is 20/3/13
- Tried creating a custom log and added IEFRAME as the event source, its still blank.

See below for virtually the same issue without an answer.
I'm trying to investigate an issue where IE crashes and finding it difficult without logs.

[Interent Explorer Log is empty always](https://superuser.com/questions/846843/interent-explorer-log-is-empty-always)

Comment: What about in Windows > Forwarded Events?

Comment: Nothing in the Forwarded Events log, oh and forgot to mention I have no filters enabled on the logs.

Comment: Have you restarted the logging service as described in the linked answer?

Comment: Yes I tried that, we are using VDI and I've tested multiple desktops they all have the same issue.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have a play and see what I can come up with. No crazy group policies being applied?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, not an easy thing to test though in a VDI environment, it will mean spinning up a new pool of desktops. I will go there if needs be.